# Is there an inversion in the sentence?

Tags: complex-sentences

The following sentence is quoted from the preface of [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-34604-3).

> Insisting on the subtle aspects and developments of no-arbitrage
>   theory more than is necessary would take space from the other theory
>   we need to address in the book and that is more important for our
>   purposes.

I have difficulty to understand the sentence precisely. Is there an inversion in the sentence? How can I rewrite it into simple sentences?

Comment: "The reader shouldn't insist on the subtle developments in no-arbitrage theory. It would take space from the theory that I really want to talk about."

Comment: It's definitely written in an obscure style.

Comment: Hello, newy. Unravelling complete sentences / comprehension is really off-topic. However. << There are two theories we need to address in [this] book. One is [the?] no-arbitrage theory, which contains subtle aspects and has had subtle developments. But in this book, our purpose is to focus on the other theory [and we consider this more important overall{?}]. We shall only devote the space we consider absolutely necessary to [the intricacies of] [the] no-arbitrage theory, as we need to maintain our focus. >>

Comment: *Insisting on [something] more than is necessary would take space [from the other theory] and [take space] that is more important for our purposes.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inversion. The subject of the verbal form "would take" is "the [gerund phrase](https://www.thoughtco.com/gerund-in-grammar-1690897)  "Insisting on the subtle aspects and developments of no-arbitrage theory more than is necessary", which functions as a noun, and the demonstrative "that" has for antecedent "the other theory we need to address in the book".

Comment: +1 Heavy subjects and main verbs that don't occur until the second line always confuse people.